# Azure SNAT exhaustion - how do I know when it is happening?

Tags: azure, networking, nat

We think we are having Azure SNAT exhaustion issues with a group of virtual machines within Cloud Foundry.  The machines are not going through a load balancer. 
 I've been through this document:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#snatexhaust

I want to find out how, if possible, to know if we are hitting SNAT exhaustion issues without having to open a support ticket with Microsoft.  Remediating or preventing the SNAT issues is NOT what I'm asking about.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just got off the phone with Microsoft Azure support.  At this time, there is no way for us as a customer to see SNAT exhaustion without opening a ticket.

Answer (score 10):

For an **Azure WebApp**, click **Diagnose and solve problems**, then in search box type **snat** then click the **SNAT Port Exhaustion** item which appears as the result of your search.

Comment: IS there any Metrics that can display the results . Actually I am making a Dashboard in azure and want to display SNAT port results in that dashboard . Is this possible ?

Answer (score 5):

The answer may be outdated. With Azure Standard LoadBalancer you will be able to see the following SNAT Metrics.

1. SNAT Connection Count
2. Allocated SNAT Ports
3. Used SNAT Ports

This is not available with Azure Basic Load Balancer, which requires support ticket to get info on SNATS.

[image: SNAT Metrics]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I have put in an enhancement request for Microsoft to enable monitoring on it: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/231545-diagnostics-and-monitoring/suggestions/36274288-apim-load-balancer-metrics-to-view-snat-metrics-st

If it sounds like a good solution make sure to up vote it!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, thank you for the answer, be sure to check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer you might find some useful tips

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find out how, if possible, to know if we are hitting SNAT
>   exhaustion issues

When SNAT port resources are exhausted, outbound flows fail. You could observe **failing outbound connections** or are **advised by support that you're exhausting SNAT ports.**

The outbound connections have a [4-minute idle timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-outbound-connections#idletimeout). This timeout is not adjustable. UDP SNAT ports generally exhaust much faster than TCP SNAT ports due to the difference in the algorithm used. So you may check the timeout flows via capturing networking packages using [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/4865) on the VM or use [Network Watcher for packet capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-packet-capture-manage-portal) on the Azure portal.

If you have any unclear in my reply, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that is good information but simply seeing failed connections does not confirm SNAT exhaustion.  Seeing the failed connections was a clue we were having an issue but there is no way to confirm SNAT exhaustion w/o a ticket to Microsoft it turns out.